# Beautifulsoup find the tag and attribute of without value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the content of the particular tag which having the attribute but no values. How can I get it for example

```
cont = '<nav></nav> <nav breadcrumbs> <a href="">aa</a></nav> <nav></nav>'
```

From the above one I want to extract the `<nav breadcrumbs> <a href="">aa</a></nav>`

So I have tried the following one

```
bread = contSoup.find("nav",{"breadcrumbs":""})
```

I have tried below one also

```
bread = contSoup.find("nav breadcrumbs")
```

Finally I'm using RegEx to get this data, I'm able to get the answer, but how can I do it from the beautiful soup

Comment: If BS supports CSS Selectors do this, `nav[breadcrumbs]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `attr=True` for this case.

```
cont = '<nav></nav> <nav breadcrumbs> <a href="">aa</a></nav> <nav></nav>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(cont, 'lxml')  # works with 'html.parser' too.
print(soup.find('nav', breadcrumbs=True))
# which is the same as print(soup.find('nav', {'breadcrumbs': True}))
```

Output:

```
<nav breadcrumbs=""> <a href="">aa</a></nav>
```